# using wait (bash posix) and fail if one process fails in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, posix, wait

I am writing a script that executes a bunch of commands in the background all at once then waits for them to all finish:

```
#!/bin/sh -fx
./p1 &
./p2 &
./p3 &
./p4 &
./p5 &
wait
```

The problem is that if one or more of these processes fail, it just keeps going.  How can I execute all of these commands at the same time and check if one or more fail?

Answer (score 5):

You can wait individual pids to get their exit status:

```
#! /bin/sh -
set -o xtrace -o noglob

./p1 & p1=$!
./p2 & p2=$!
./p3 & p3=$!
./p4 & p4=$!
./p5 & p5=$!
fail=0
for pid in "$p1" "$p2" "$p3" "$p4" "$p5"; do
  wait "$pid" || fail=$(( fail + 1 ))
done
echo>&2 "$fail failed"
exit "$(( fail > 0 ))"
```

Note that we don't necessarily wait for those processes in the order they terminate, but `wait pid` should still work at retrieving the pid's exit status even if `wait` is  invoked after the pid has already exited.

Another approach is to use the `pipefail` option which is supported by most `sh` implementations¹ and [will be in the next version of the POSIX standard](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=789):

```
#! /bin/sh -
set -o xtrace -o noglob -o pipefail
alias r='<&3 3<&- >&4 4>&-'

die() { printf>&2 '%s\n' "$@"; exit 1; }

{
  r ./p1 | r ./p2 | r ./p3 | r ./p4 | r ./p5
} 3<&0 4>&1 || die "At least one of them failed"
```

We start them in a pipeline, but don't use the pipe. We restore stdin and stdout of those processes to the original ones as saved on fd 3 and 4 with the help of that `r` alias.

---

<sup>¹ though unfortunately not `dash` yet, even though most other ash-based shells already support it.</sup>

Comment: Out of curiosity, do p1-p5 *need* to be in quotes?  (There aren't any spaces in the pid, so is it force of habit?)

Comment: Quoting is not about spaces. Omitting quotes in list contexts is split+glob which wouldn't make sense here. The splitting part is done on characters of `$IFS`, not spaces (though space is in the default value of `$IFS`). See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346), especially here the *What about [ $# -gt 1 ]* section.